# "npm install express socket.io" vs "npm install socket.io"

Tags: node.js, express, npm, socket.io

I am reading a book to learn Firebase. In the section about Socket.io, there is an npm command I do not understand, it is

```
npm install express socket.io
```

What does the "express" do here? Or it is just a redundant word? If it does mean something, what is the difference between the command above and that without "express":

```
npm install socket.io
```

I have tried both and they both work. Please help explain, thanks a lot!

Comment: The first installs two packages (and their dependencies), the second installs one package (and its dependencies). If `express` is one of `socket.io` dependencies, there is no difference — it's like "meet Bobby and his siblings" and "meet Bobby and his siblings and his sister and her siblings", somewhat redundant.

Comment: if you have just read the npm docs, you wouldn't hit that wall of uneducation

Answer (score 1):

With `npm install`, you have the ability to install multiple packages. Just separate each package with a space.

> npm install express socket.io

The above command will install [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) web framework and [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io)

You could have installed the above packages individually, like so:

> npm install express
>
> npm install socket.io

Comment: Yeah for precisely answering the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

express is a nodeJs framework. 
Basically, it will be used to create a node server. 
I believe if you read further you will definitely see where it is used.

You can't use socket.io without a server.

Answer (score 0):

**npm** is **node package manager** used for install different packages in project as per requirement

to start any nodejs project , first command is used :

`npm init`

then it will create `package.json` file in your root directory of project

to install a package :

`npm install package_name`

to install a multiple packages :

```
npm install package_name1 package_name2 package_name3 package_name4
```

to install a package globally **-g** is used :

`npm install -g package_name`

**--save** is used to save the package required for the application to run.

`npm install --save package_name`

after installing package , it will create entry in dependencies in package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "package_name1":"version_of_package",
    "package_name2":"version_of_package",
}
```

**--save-dev** is used to save the package for development purpose

`npm install --save-dev package_name`

after installing package , it will create entry in dev dependencies in package.json file

```
"devDependencies": {
    "package_name1":"version_of_package",
    "package_name2":"version_of_package",
}
```